# Gcm Api AdvertiserLandingPages.List() does not apply advertiser id filter to landing pages

Tags: c#, dfareporting

I am trying to get a list of advertiser landing pages for a specific advertiser only as described in [docs](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v4/advertiserLandingPages/list) using code below, which mimics the [sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/blob/main/dotnet/v4/Advertisers/GetAdvertiserLandingPages.cs):

```
var reportingService = new DfareportingService(
            new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "MyAppName",
            });

    var profileId = <profileId>;
    var advertiserId = <advertiserId>;
    var req = reportingService.AdvertiserLandingPages.List(profileId);
    req.AdvertiserIds = new List<string> { advertiserId };
        
    var result = req.Execute();
```

In the result, I expect to get only landing pages for advertiser with Id 14. However, this filter does not workd, and the API returns all landing pages.

What am I missing?

The result includes all landing pages.
I expect to get only landing pages with `AdvertiserId` equal to the ony specified in request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As follows from response to [my request](https://groups.google.com/g/google-doubleclick-for-advertisers-api/c/3w7THTGRJGc/m/gQLt_8oFAgAJ), filtering by advertiser ids no longer works in version 4 (docs have not been updated to reflect the change).